# Is there another way to transform multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a multi dimensional array and I only want to transform specific keys in a multi dimensional array.

Here's the example multi dimensional array:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'id' => 0,
        'payment_method' => 2,
        'amount' => 100,
        'check_no' => '',
        'remarks' => '',
        'check_date' => '2020-01-13',
        'bank_account_id' => NULL,
        'surcharge_id' => NULL,
        'card_number' => '',
        'customer_name' => '',
        'merchant_number' => '',
        'batch_number' => '',
        'approval_number' => '',
        'other_reference_1' => '',
        'other_reference_3' => '',
        'other_reference_2' => '',
        'based_amount' => 0,
        'actual_amount' => 0,
        'total_charge' => 0,
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'id' => 0,
        'payment_method' => 2,
        'amount' => 150,
        'check_no' => '',
        'remarks' => '',
        'check_date' => '2020-01-13',
        'bank_account_id' => NULL,
        'surcharge_id' => NULL,
        'card_number' => '',
        'customer_name' => '',
        'merchant_number' => '',
        'batch_number' => '',
        'approval_number' => '',
        'other_reference_1' => '',
        'other_reference_3' => '',
        'other_reference_2' => '',
        'based_amount' => 0,
        'actual_amount' => 0,
        'total_charge' => 0,
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'id' => 0,
        'payment_method' => 2,
        'amount' => 100,
        'check_no' => '',
        'remarks' => '',
        'check_date' => '2020-01-13',
        'bank_account_id' => NULL,
        'surcharge_id' => NULL,
        'card_number' => '',
        'customer_name' => '',
        'merchant_number' => '',
        'batch_number' => '',
        'approval_number' => '',
        'other_reference_1' => '',
        'other_reference_3' => '',
        'other_reference_2' => '',
        'based_amount' => 0,
        'actual_amount' => 0,
        'total_charge' => 0,
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
    )
)
```

I only want specific keys to transform for example I only want transaction_id, transaction_status, amount, etc.

Then the expected output would be:

```
array (
    0 =>
    array (
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
        'amount' => 100
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
        'amount' => 100
    ),
    2 =>
    array (
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
        'amount' => 100
    )
)
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: You should mention what you've attempted and where the problem lies. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Using `forecah` loop it possible like this.

```
<?php 
$a = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'id' => 0,
        'payment_method' => 2,
        'amount' => 100,
        'check_no' => '',
        'remarks' => '',
        'check_date' => '2020-01-13',
        'bank_account_id' => NULL,
        'surcharge_id' => NULL,
        'card_number' => '',
        'customer_name' => '',
        'merchant_number' => '',
        'batch_number' => '',
        'approval_number' => '',
        'other_reference_1' => '',
        'other_reference_3' => '',
        'other_reference_2' => '',
        'based_amount' => 0,
        'actual_amount' => 0,
        'total_charge' => 0,
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'id' => 0,
        'payment_method' => 2,
        'amount' => 150,
        'check_no' => '',
        'remarks' => '',
        'check_date' => '2020-01-13',
        'bank_account_id' => NULL,
        'surcharge_id' => NULL,
        'card_number' => '',
        'customer_name' => '',
        'merchant_number' => '',
        'batch_number' => '',
        'approval_number' => '',
        'other_reference_1' => '',
        'other_reference_3' => '',
        'other_reference_2' => '',
        'based_amount' => 0,
        'actual_amount' => 0,
        'total_charge' => 0,
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'id' => 0,
        'payment_method' => 2,
        'amount' => 100,
        'check_no' => '',
        'remarks' => '',
        'check_date' => '2020-01-13',
        'bank_account_id' => NULL,
        'surcharge_id' => NULL,
        'card_number' => '',
        'customer_name' => '',
        'merchant_number' => '',
        'batch_number' => '',
        'approval_number' => '',
        'other_reference_1' => '',
        'other_reference_3' => '',
        'other_reference_2' => '',
        'based_amount' => 0,
        'actual_amount' => 0,
        'total_charge' => 0,
        'transaction_id' => 47,
        'transaction_status' => 0,
    )
);
$new_array = array();
foreach($a as $value){
    $new_array[] = array(
            'transaction_id' => $value['transaction_id'],
            'transaction_status' => $value['transaction_status'],
            'amount' => $value['amount']
            );
}
print_r($new_array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 47
            [transaction_status] => 0
            [amount] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 47
            [transaction_status] => 0
            [amount] => 150
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 47
            [transaction_status] => 0
            [amount] => 100
        )

)
```

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: Hi. I forgot to include that I use foreach, and I'm thinking another way to transform multi dimensional array. By the way, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array-map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php), [array-intersect-key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [array-fill-keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php)as:

```
$keys = ['transaction_id','transaction_status','amount'];
$keys = array_fill_keys($keys,0);
$arr = array_map(function($e) use ($keys) { return array_intersect_key($e, $keys);}, $arr);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Y9csl)

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel Array Helper

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$newArray = [];
$keys = ['transaction_id', 'transaction_status', 'amount'];

foreach($array as $item) {
    $newArray[] = Arr::only($item, $keys);
}

return $newArray;
```